# Login as console in Windows Server 2008 by editing .RDP file

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp

It used to be able add this line `connect to console:i:1` in .rdp file in Windows Server 2003. However it doesn't work in Windows Server 2008. Is this changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no console session in W2K8.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947723

Comment: I saw you mention this in a previous post. Thanks for linking the KB. I would give you +5 for that insite.

Comment: Glad to help...